# Does elasticsearch support conditional queries?

Tags: elasticsearch

I know that solr supports if conditions in the query (e.g., `fl=if(min(2,myField),2,myField)`). I am not able to find similar functionality in elasticsearch. The closest I can find is [script fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/script-fields/).

1. Does elasticsearch support nested function queries like `min(max(myField,0),1)`?
2. If so, does it support such queries for sorting as well, like `sort=min(max(myField,0),1)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Scripting](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/scripting/) is what you're looking for. The default scripting language is [mvel](http://mvel.codehaus.org/), but you can easily install plugins that support other languages, like [javascript](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-lang-javascript), [groovy](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-lang-groovy), [python](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-lang-python). You can also write your own native script in Java.

You can use scripts in different apis, here are some examples:

- [script fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/script-fields/) as you mentioned, to get back fields that are not in your documents but created on-the-fly
- script based [sorting](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/sort/), to sort your documents based on the result of a script
- [script filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/script-filter/), to filter based on a script
- boosting using [custom score query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-score-query/) and [custom filters score query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-filters-score-query/)
- making [facets](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/)

It's possible to preload scripts placing them on file system, from the documentation page:

> Scripts can always be provided as part of the relevant API, but they
>   can also be preloaded by placing them under `config/scripts` and then
>   referencing them by the script name (instead of providing the full
>   script). This helps reduce the amount of data passed between the
>   client and the nodes.
>
> The name of the script is derived from the hierarchy of directories it
>   exists under, and the file name without the lang extension. For
>   example, a script placed under `config/scripts/group1/group2/test.py`
>   will be named `group1_group2_test`.

Only native scripts written in java have to implement an interface. In case of either mvel, javascript python or groovy, you can just write the script that you need on file instead of passing it together with the relevant api and refer to it using its name.

Comment: @javana Great. In most of the examples, I see simple scripts like script" : "doc['field_name'].value * factor" . Have you come across something that talks about how to plugin an myPython.py file and goes into details like where the .py/.js file should be put, what methods & signatures it needs to implement etc.?

Comment: It's hard for me to follow here but I saw you posted on the elasticsearch google group a specific question with more details. I would consider this question answered given its title and content, but you are free to create a new one with a detailed description whenever you feel like you need more help.